# What is the /dev file name of my WiFi adapter which plugs into a female dual coax socket, not a USB socket, on my server?

Tags: networking, drivers, server, usb

I bought an Aorus motherboard and made a pretty decent home server out of it (with other purchased parts). The mobo came with a WiFi adapter which plugs/screws into the mobo peripheral socket bay via a radio-like (so like, 2 cable-type sockets, 2 coaxes) socket. I am running Ubuntu (not sure what version, downloaded recently so possibly Bionic, but the server CLI version). X-win isn't installed. The OS didn't come with `iw` (the new version of `iwconfig`) but it did come with `ifconfig`. I can't copy paste the output of `ifconfig` or other commands from the server easily because I am writing this post on my laptop PC (also Ubuntu Bionic, non-server, yes x-win), so I will try to paraphrase outputs as best I can. In any case, `ifconfig` yields just `lo`, and going `ifconfig up wlan0` doesn't work (`wlan0: Host name lookup failure`).

The output of `dmesg` on the server is huge, and going `dmesg | less` would take probably hours (hyperbole?) to look through for the WiFi card. I had two USB WiFi cards also plugged into the server, but doing the following indicated they weren't detected in the devices `/dev` folder:

```
dir /dev
```

plug in wifi adapter

```
dir /dev
```

unplug wifi adapter

```
dir /dev
```

Check which /dev file showed up when the wifi adapter was plugged in

So, no changes to `/dev` contents when the USB wifi adapters were plugged into the server. I could try this for the coax wifi adapter that shipped with the mobo, but I expect it wouldn't show up either, and it doesn't really matter whether it does or not because I really need it mounted. Currently my server is only on `localhost`, without an ethernet connection (has an ethernet socket, but none in the wall in my room--only a phone and a coax socket in the wall). I don't want to bring the server downstairs to the router and plug straight into it wired b/c it's a heavy giant Rosewill case, so that's mondo inconvenient. I figured transferring files would be easy enough. Turns out it is: I was able to `dpkg -L iw` and `cp iw` to a USB flash drive and onto `/bin` on the server from the PC laptop, so it works there now. But I don't know which `/dev` file is the wifi adapter on the server, so I can't just go `iw up [wifi adapter name]`.

I hope this all makes sense. Looking forward to your engagement in my problems.

Much appreciated,

Mike

Comment: As far as I know, there are three ways to attach a wireless device to a computer. First is PCI. You can find those devices with: `lspci` Next is USB; find those with : `lsusb` Finally, in tablets and other small devices, SDIO. Find those with: `dmesg | grep -i sdio` Any help? Does the mobo manual have a specific name for this socket?

Comment: "so like, 2 cable-type sockets, 2 coaxes" Aren't those simply the antenna connectors?

Comment: Thanks, chili. None of those sockets are used in my adapter's connection; as you point out, yes, it is an antenna connector. So it's not PCI, it's not USB, and it's not SDIO. So, not to put you down or anything, but no, that doesn't help. I mean it eliminates some options, which helps, but it doesn't give me the solution. What I am going to do is look into the mobo's user manual, find out which brand of antenna it is, and see if there is some firmware I can download and upload onto the server to use. Thanks!

Comment: Nix that. lspci works. Thanks!

Comment: Okay I found a firmware package from Intel that may work. Where should I install it on the server?

Comment: The PCI WiFi antenna is detected on pci: 7 network. It is DISABLED, and the driver is iwlwifi. How do I enable it?

Comment: I solved it. On to bigger, greater problems! (See https://askubuntu.com/questions/1235782/how-to-enable-an-intel-pci-wifi-adapter-which-is-not-enabled-access-denied).

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo lshw | less
```

Find your device from the tree. Under `logical name:` will be the name of the device.